# F-string error in Python - What does the equals sign mean?

Tags: python, f-string

New to python.
I am getting:

> Invalid syntax  line 1

I understand that the fstring error can show up on line one. These lines are pretty much taken from [this page in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). There is syntax I am unfamiliar with `{err=}`. I tried searching but the `=` is so ubiquitous it's like a needle in a haystack.

What is wrong with what is below? I assume it is somehow connected to the `=`. If I remove the `=` then the error flag goes away.

What does the `=` do?

The two places that use this error handling look like this:

```
except  BaseException as err:
    print(f"Shadow retrieval exception: {err=}, {type(err)=}")
```

and

```
except  BaseException as err:
    print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running? The `=` was added in 3.8. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and [What’s New In Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging)

Comment: That's a typing shortcut.  `f"Hello {i=}"`, if i is 3, will retuirn `"Hello i=3"`.  That is, it enters literal `"i="` and then the value of i.

Comment: Thank you all. I was developing in 3.7.3. That was leading to the use of the `=` being flagged an error.